# Issue with DB pool

Tags: java, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am using DB pool ([DB Pool](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/)) in my application. My DAO code is like:

```
static {
        try {
            PropertyUtil propertyUtil = new PropertyUtil();
            propertyUtil.getBundle(Constants.DB_PROPERTIES);
            String dburl = propertyUtil.getProperty("dburl");
            String dbuserName = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbuserName");
            String dbpassword = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbpassword");
            String dbclass = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbclass");
            String dbpoolName = propertyUtil.getProperty("dbpoolName");
            int dbminPool = Integer.parseInt(propertyUtil
                    .getProperty("dbminPool"));
            int dbmaxPool = Integer.parseInt(propertyUtil
                    .getProperty("dbmaxPool"));
            int dbmaxSize = Integer.parseInt(propertyUtil
                    .getProperty("dbmaxSize"));
            Class.forName(dbclass).newInstance();
            moPool = new ConnectionPool(dbpoolName, dbminPool, dbmaxPool,
                    dbmaxSize, dburl, dbuserName, dbpassword);
            moLogWrapper.info("Connection pool size: -"+Integer.valueOf(moPool.getSize()));
        } catch (ApplicationException aoAppEx) {
            moLogWrapper
                    .error(aoAppEx.getMessage(), aoAppEx.fillInStackTrace());
            new ApplicationException(aoAppEx.getMessage(),
                    aoAppEx.fillInStackTrace());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException aoIllEx) {
            moLogWrapper
                    .error(aoIllEx.getMessage(), aoIllEx.fillInStackTrace());
            new ApplicationException(aoIllEx.getMessage(),
                    aoIllEx.fillInStackTrace());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException aoCnfEx) {
            moLogWrapper
                    .error(aoCnfEx.getMessage(), aoCnfEx.fillInStackTrace());
            new ApplicationException(aoCnfEx.getMessage(),
                    aoCnfEx.fillInStackTrace());
        } catch (InstantiationException aoIEx) {
            moLogWrapper.error(aoIEx.getMessage(), aoIEx.fillInStackTrace());
            new ApplicationException(aoIEx.getMessage(),
                    aoIEx.fillInStackTrace());
        }

    }
```

and my openConnection() method is :

```
public void openConnection() throws ApplicationException {
        moLogWrapper.info("inside openConnection method");
        try {
            loCon = moPool.getConnection();
            // moLogWrapper.info(moPool.getSize());
        } catch (SQLException aoSqlEx) {
            moLogWrapper
                    .error(aoSqlEx.getMessage(), aoSqlEx.fillInStackTrace());
            if (null != loCon) {
                loCon = null;
            }
                throw new ApplicationException(1002, aoSqlEx);
        } catch (Exception aoEx) {
            moLogWrapper.error(aoEx.fillInStackTrace());
            throw new ApplicationException(aoEx.getMessage(),
                    aoEx.fillInStackTrace());
        }
        moLogWrapper.info("exiting openConnection method");
    }
```

The problem is that I am getting null in .openConnection method from Connection pool class.
There is a DEBUG log printed in my logs as well, which prints following line:

```
[snaq.db.ConnectionPool.sp] sp: Checkout - 10/10 (HitRate=40.186916%) - null returned
```

I am not able to understand why null is being returned and how can i debug the actual issue.

**Edit:**

My application runs fine but throws starts throwing this error sometime suddenly.

I am using postgres as my database.

Comment: Can you please post the full error stacktrace ?

Comment: Are there any errors at start up ?

Comment: @Santosh: Please see my edit section in the question. The application usually runs fine but starts throwing this error suddenly.

Comment: @sheldonCooper: The rest of the stacktrace that I have is from my own application, which is nullpointerexception due to connection being null.

Comment: @sheldonCooper: moPool is not null, but the value returned by moPool.getConnection() is null.

Comment: @Ankit, after you have used the connection, are you releasing it back to the pool? This generally done by calling `close()` method on pooled connections.

Comment: @Santosh: Yes, I am releasing it back to the pool. But is there a way to check if there are any idle connections and release them manually if possible.

Comment: @Ankit, Yes I guess you can check. At any given point in time, the `ConnectionPool` class should have a method which gives you the current connection pool status.

Comment: But how do i release them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `javax.sql.DataSource` to get connection.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class JdbcConnection {

private static DataSource dataSource;

static{
   //make DB connection here with datasource
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
return dataSource.getConnection();
}

}
```

Comment: My application is already live on production environment. I don't want to change my connection pooling way unless I find any issue that can't be solved, which I don't think is there.